# What is the best practices to make checkbox tree using indeterminate javascript HTML?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a checkbox tree where i need three states of checkbox, I know there is two state of checkbox, but i have to use indeterminate

1. Check
2. Uncheck
3. Indeterminate

How can i developed these type of tree using javascript?

Comment: You mean actually using a single checkbox input element with three states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div id="page-wrap">

   <h1>Indeterminate Checkboxes</h1>

 <ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tall" id="tall">
        <label for="tall">Tall Things</label>

        <ul>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="tall-1" id="tall-1">
                 <label for="tall-1">Buildings</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2" id="tall-2">
                 <label for="tall-2">Giants</label>

                 <ul>
                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2-1" id="tall-2-1">
                         <label for="tall-2-1">Andre</label>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2-2" id="tall-2-2">
                         <label for="tall-2-2">Paul Bunyan</label>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="tall-3" id="tall-3">
                 <label for="tall-3">Two sandwiches</label>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="short" id="short">
        <label for="short">Short Things</label>

        <ul>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="short-1" id="short-1">
                 <label for="short-1">Smurfs</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="short-2" id="short-2">
                 <label for="short-2">Mushrooms</label>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="short-3" id="short-3">
                 <label for="short-3">One Sandwich</label>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>

   $(function() {
      // Apparently click is better chan change? Cuz IE?
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
      var checked = $(this).prop("checked"),
          container = $(this).parent(),
          siblings = container.siblings();

      container.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
          indeterminate: false,
          checked: checked
      });

      function checkSiblings(el) {
          var parent = el.parent().parent(),
              all = true;

          el.siblings().each(function() {
              return all = ($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
          });

          if (all && checked) {
              parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                  indeterminate: false,
                  checked: checked
              });
              checkSiblings(parent);
          } else if (all && !checked) {
              parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checked);
              parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("indeterminate", (parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0));
              checkSiblings(parent);
          } else {
              el.parents("li").children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                  indeterminate: true,
                  checked: false
              });
          }
        }

        checkSiblings(container);
      });
    });
```

Comment: If you tick the root node then a child it correctly sets indeterminate on all parents up the tree, but if you tick again it doesn't tick all the parents back up the tree, it keeps them as indeterminate (even though everything is ticked again)

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial one from scratch: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/MgYs7/1/.

```
var span = document.getElementById('span');
span.setAttribute('data-state', 0);

span.onselectstart = function() { return false }; // prevent selecting, doesn't look too good

span.onclick = function() {
    var state = span.getAttribute('data-state') - 0; // convert to number

    if(state === 0) { // set next symbol
        span.innerHTML = 'V';
    } else if(state === 1) {
        span.innerHTML = 'X';
    } else {
        span.innerHTML = '';
    }

    span.setAttribute('data-state', (state + 1) % 3); // set state; 3 will be 0 again
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use already developed plugins (or read their code if you are just curious how to manipulate the checkboxes' states).
Just drop one of them. If you choose [niTree](https://github.com/AlexLibs/niTree) plugin I can help you with any questions concerning the code:

https://github.com/AlexLibs/niTree

Answer (score -1):

I would use values -1, 0 and 1. Every onclick the attached function checks its value.

-1 = Indeterminate
0 = unchecked
1 = checked.

If 0 change to 1
If 1 change to -1
If -1 change to 0

If the value = -1 add this property (e.g. via jQuery) to the checkbox:
`$(checkbox).prop("indeterminate", true);` 
For every other value the indeterminate value should be `false`.
See [this link](http://css-tricks.com/13467-indeterminate-checkboxes) for  example

Of course your tree logic should act on what its value is going to be e.g. unchecking children or setting parent at indeterminate.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to go about making it.

Comment: I've modified my answer with a hint for setting the checkbox indeterminate.

Comment: If you actually read the site you linked us to, it explains that this does not change the state.

Comment: There will always only be two states. The only way possible is to interact on the visual via the checkbox its current value.

Comment: Unless you implement your own tri-state checkbox control, which is what I thought this question was about.

Comment: Then he needs to create his own markup language I'm afraid. Or find one that already does what he needs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_markup_languages